# Networking - VPN DNS confusion

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, lan

When I am running a VPN client, the hostname of my gateway / router "fritz.box" is no longer resolvable when I try to reach it from my web browser.

This I can't understand properly, because it is the router itself which resolves this hostname. Why should this be affected, if running the VPN client, if it this is still within my local network?

I can however reach any of my local devices without issue, via their local IP addresses when the VPN client is running. Why exactly is this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach local devices by IP because local IP addresses are not sent through the VPN tunnel.

You can not reach your local devices by DNS name because your DNS requests are tunneled through VPN. This is pretty much default behavior. Not doing so creates a [DNS Leak](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_leak) that can reveal private information despite using a VPN.

You didn’t provide any details about your VPN setup. You can adjust this behavior, but with the added security issues mentioned above.

Comment: How and where is it decided not to send the local IP addresses through the VPN tunnel? External IP addresses are sent through the tunnel however? The VPN client is only running on the computer. Isn't it the router which understands what is a local IP address or not? Thanks

Comment: @Engineer999 A “local IP” address, being one that is in the same logical subnet as the computer, is determined by the computer according to the subnet mask. IP addresses that have the same network address are on the same “local” network. It’s the computer that decides if it will send the packet directly to a local device, or attempt to route it through your gateway. To determine the network address the IP address is combined with the subnet mask using a logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

VPN is just like a tunnel over your internet connection. Whatever you do is transferred with encryption. And when you connect a VPN, all your traffic is routed through the network of VPN (you can run a simple traceroute to figure out comparing to the traffic is which is routed by your original gateway). And when you try to access the local router/gateway with its hostname, it will not ask your DNS server, where the mapping of your router is contained. So you will not be able to access it. For a workaround, you can add an entry to your HOSTS file (%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) to resolve this issue like:

```
Gateway's_IP_adress fritz.box
```